# Extjs store.filter by date range

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3, date-range

Here is my code, I am trying to filter the 'CollectTime' by allowing it to be a date range.

I don't see in the docs where I can add this nor do I see an example that shows this working correctly.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
listeners: {
    'load': function(store) {
            if ('color' in $_GET) {
                    store.filter([
                            {property: 'color' , value: $_GET['color'] , anyMatch: true , caseSensitive: false}
                    ]);
            }
            if ('priority' in $_GET) {
                    store.filter([
                            {property: 'precedence' , value: $_GET['priority'] , anyMatch: true , caseSensitive: false}
                    ]);
            }
            if ('startdate' in $_GET) {
                    store.filter([
                            {property: 'CollectTime' , value: $_GET['startdate'] , anyMatch: true , caseSensitive: false}
                    ]);
            }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use filterBy method instead of filter and provide a filter function

here is an example:

```
...
if ( 'startdate' in $_GET ) {
    store.filterBy( function( rec, id ){
        return rec.data.CollectTime >= $_GET['startdate'] && rec.data.CollectTime <= $_GET['enddate'];
    } );
}
...
```